# Kafka , Spark large csv file (4Go)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-kafka, rdd

I am developing an integration channel with kafka and spark, which will process batchs and streaming.

for batch processing, I entered huge CSV files (4 GB).

I'm considering two solutions:

1. Send the whole file to the file system and send a message to kafka
   with the file address, and the spark job will read the file from the
   FS and turn on it.
2. cut the file before kafka in unit message (with apache nifi) and
   send to treat the batch as streaming in the spark job.

What do you think is the best solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing code to place the file on the file system, you can use that same code to submit the Spark job to the job tracker.  The job tracker becomes the task queue and processes your submitted files as Spark jobs.

This would be a more simplistic way of implementing #1 but it has drawbacks. The main drawback being that you have to tune resource allocation to make sure you don't under allocate for cases if your data set is extremely large.  If you over allocate resources for the job, then your task queue potentially grows while tasks are waiting for resources.  The advantage is that there aren't very many moving parts to maintain and troubleshoot.

Using nifi to cut a large file down and having spark handle the pieces as a stream would probably make it easier to utilize the cluster resources more effectively.  If your cluster is servicing random jobs on top of this data ingestion, this might be the better way to go.  The drawbacks here might be that you need to do extra work to process all parts of a single file in one transactional context, you may have to do a few extra things to make sure you aren't going to lose the data delivered by Kafka, etc.

If this is for a batch operation, maybe method 2 would be considered overkill.  The setup seems pretty complex for reading a CSV file even if it is a potentially really large file.  If you had a problem with the velocity of the CSV file, a number of ever-changing sources for the CSV, or a high error rate then NiFi would make a lot of sense.

It's hard to suggest the best solution.  If it were me, I'd start with the variation of #1 to make it work first.  Then you make it work better by introducing more system parts depending on how your approach performs with an acceptable level of accuracy in handling anomalies in the input file.  You may find that your biggest problem is trying to identify errors in input files during a large scale ingestion.

Comment: Thank you for your informative feedback.
In fact, we chose the second one. because it corresponds more to our use case